# Fill input field of foreignkeyfield from database in Django

Tags: django

I am using a `foreignkey` field of a model as an input field in the html form because I want a user input if the value is not present in the database. So I just gave an input tag and in views I take the value and assign it to the form field. Now if the userprofile is already created then the pincode value will be there. How can I prepopulate the input field in the html with the value from the database?

**profile.html**

```
<form method="POST" id="userProfileForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   {% csrf_token %}
   .
   .
   .
   <div>
     <label for="input_pincode">Pincode</label>
     <input id="input_pincode" type="text" name="input_pincode">                
  </div><br>
  .
  .
  .
</form>
```

**models.py**

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    .
    .
    .
    pincode = models.ForeignKey(Pincode, models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
```

**forms.py**

```
class UserProfileUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UserProfileUpdateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for visible in self.visible_fields():
            visible.field.widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ['pincode', other_fields]
```

**views.py**

```
def profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        u_form = UserUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        up_form = UserProfileUpdateForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user.userprofile)
        if u_form.is_valid() and up_form.is_valid():
            u_form.save()
            uncommitted_up_form = up_form.save(commit=False)
            if request.POST['city']:
                pin = Pincode.objects.get_or_create(city_id=request.POST['city'], pincode=request.POST['input_pincode'])[0]
                uncommitted_up_form.pincode = pin

            #other logic
            uncommitted_up_form.save()
            messages.success(request, f'Your profile has been updated!')
            return redirect('profile')
```

Here in the html file I want to show the value of `userprofile.pincode.name` in the `input_pincode` box. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of how to show the value of `userprofile.pincode.name` in the `input_pincode` box. You can try like this.

in views.py

```
name = userprofile.pincode.name
return render(request, "profile.html", {"name ": name }) OR return render(request, 
"profile.html", {"name ": userprofile.pincode.name})
```

in HTML template

```
<form method="POST" id="userProfileForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 {% csrf_token %}
 <div>
 <label for="input_pincode">Pincode</label>
 <input id="input_pincode" value="{{name}}" type="text" name="input_pincode">                
 </div><br>
</form>
```

Comment: Can't it be taken from up_form dirrectly? something like {{ up_form.pincode.name }}? I know this gives the html of the select option but is there anything like this?

Comment: I am just worried without passing or rendering how it will come in html? I mean return redirect('profile'). How value will come from views code to html. You have to use this  return render(request, "profile.html", {"name ": up_form.pincode.name}).

Comment: I thought since I am passing the instance here `up_form = UserProfileUpdateForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user.userprofile)`, the form will contain the value of pincode.

Comment: Did you tried this instead of return redirect('profile'), use render(request, "profile.html", {"up_form": up_form}) and in html {{up_form.pincode.name}}

Comment: check this use value="{{up_form.pincode.name}}" in input field.

Comment: If I do that then I get `<select name=---name">`.